# Why is a paleoTS function not working?

Tags: function, r, package

I have loaded paleoTS in R (2.13.0) and tried to use the `fit3models.joint` function, but can't. I tried reinstalling but it assures me paleoTS is already there! Help appreciated:

```
Error: could not find function "fit3models.joint"
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: package 'paleoTS' is in use and will not be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information yet.  I see no evidence that `fit3models.joint` is a function in the `paleoTS` package: did you mean `fit3models` ... ? or `fit3models(...,method='Joint')` (based on the looking at the examples in `?fit3models`  ?

```
install.packages("paleoTS")
library("paleoTS")
ls(pos=2)
 [1] "add.OU.curves"         "akaike.wts"            "as.paleoTS"           
 [4] "as.paleoTSfit"         "cat.paleoTS"           "compareModels"        
 [7] "fit3models"            "fitGpunc"              "fit.sgs"              
[10] "IC"                    "ln.paleoTS"            "logL.covTrack"        
[13] "logL.GRW"              "logL.joint.GRW"        "logL.joint.OU"        
[16] "logL.joint.punc"       "logL.joint.punc.omega" "logL.joint.Stasis"    
[19] "logL.joint.URW"        "logL.Mult"             "logL.Mult.covTrack"   
[22] "logL.punc"             "logL.punc.omega"       "logL.SameMs"          
[25] "logL.SameVs"           "logL.sgs"              "logL.sgs.omega"       
[28] "logL.Stasis"           "logL.URW"              "LRI"                  
[31] "lynchD"                "mle.GRW"               "mle.Stasis"           
[34] "mle.URW"               "opt.covTrack"          "opt.covTrack.Mult"    
[37] "opt.GRW"               "opt.GRW.shift"         "opt.joint.GRW"        
[40] "opt.joint.OU"          "opt.joint.punc"        "opt.joint.Stasis"     
[43] "opt.joint.URW"         "opt.punc"              "opt.RW.Mult"          
[46] "opt.RW.SameMs"         "opt.RW.SameVs"         "opt.sgs"              
[49] "opt.Stasis"            "opt.URW"               "ou.M"                 
[52] "ou.V"                  "plot.paleoTS"          "pool.var"             
[55] "read.paleoTS"          "shift2gg"              "shifts"               
[58] "sim.covTrack"          "sim.GRW"               "sim.GRW.shift"        
[61] "sim.OU"                "sim.punc"              "sim.sgs"              
[64] "sim.Stasis"            "split4punc"            "std.paleoTS"          
[67] "sub.paleoTS"           "test.var.het"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well it works on a Mac with R 2.8.0, so I guess it is. Hunt and Carrano (2010) state on page 253: "The three models can be fit and compared using the appropriate 
function from the paleoTS package:
fit3models.joint(cantiusL)
fit3models.joint(cantiusLW).
The  outputs  from  these  two  function  calls  are 
summarized  in Table  2.    For  m1  length,  directional 
evolution merits substantially more model support than 
the random walk model (higher log-likelihood, lower 
AICC)."

Comment: The package has probably changed in the last two years (2.8.0 is 2.5 years old, and a paper published in 2010 was probably prepared in 2009). Does reading through the `?fit3models` give you any clues?  I would strongly suspect that `fit3models(cantiusL,method="Joint")` would be equivalent to the first command specified above ...

Comment: Cheers. That's great - it seems that is indeed the same. However what it doesn't do is print the model parameters. On the help page http://127.0.0.1:25160/library/paleoTS/html/fit3models.html it says "If silent=TRUE, a list is returned with element 'modelFits' that has the same dataframe, plus an element 'parameters' with the sub-elements for all the parameter estimates.", but silent = TRUE instead seems to stop all output (what you'd expect from "silent"!).

Comment: It's there, it just doesn't look like it (there is an `invisible()` command around the returned value in the function.  If you do `myfit <- fit3models(mydata,method="Joint",silent=TRUE)` and then print `myfit` (or extract components from it; `myfit$modelFits` or `myfit$parameters`) you should get what you want.

Comment: Hi again. Having the same trouble with the fitContinuous function described in Hunt and Carrano - it seems not to exist now. I guess the authors are the people to contact, but any ideas on how to do the same thing but in the newest version?

Comment: Sorry, I'm at the end of my knowledge. I can't find the Hunt and Carrano reference, and I don't know what `fitContinuous` does. Some thoughts for moving forward: (1) contact `maintainer("paleoTS")`. (2) contact Hunt and Carrano. (3) poke around in `help(package="paleoTS")` to see what you can discover. (4) go to http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/paleoTS/ to retrieve older versions of the package (download, set working directory appropriately, and install using `install.packages([FILENAME],repos=NULL,type="source")`). Good luck ...

Comment: PS.  I think you're looking in the wrong package -- try the `geiger` package. http://www.r-phylo.org/wiki/HowTo/InferringModelsForContinuousData ... for better advice, going to `r-sig-phylo@r-project.org` may be more helpful ...